# phonegap windows phone, works android and ios but not windows?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, cordova, visual-studio-debugging

I have a phonegap app that works in android and ios but when I port it over to windows phone it is not working. It loads up on the emulator just fine, it shows the page rendered and styled great but clicking the login button on the page does nothing. I tried disabling all javascript files except the cordova file and trying an "alert()" and that did not work. How do you debug javascript errors, the debugger that runs during emulation only shows this:

```
GapBrowser_Navigated :: /app/www/login.html
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.ServiceModel.dll'
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf6200ba) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.SR.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf0d00ea) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I have no idea how to debug this (and reading posts it sounds like the info about shouldn't even be a problem), can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey danny,even me also getting same error.have you got any solution yet ? plz inform me here when you get the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826387/how-to-run-existing-phonegapios-app-in-visualstudio-for-windows-development

Comment: Read my answer below, that is what was happening to me. I have to wait for the jquery to be ready AND for cordova to be ready before executing any javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was caused by javascript using the cordova api firing before the deviceready event, it never happened in android or ios but I guess the execution times in the windows one caused race conditions. Also I used a "throw" to kill javascript after doing a window.location just so nothing else got executed and that doesn't work on windows but does on the other two.

Comment: So in the end you did not fix the problem for windows phone?

Comment: @frederico-schardong I had to wrap a lot of javascript inside the deviceready event within the jquery ready event `$(function() {document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){`