# How to run existing phonegap(ios) app in VisualStudio for windows development

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-phone-7.1, cordova-2.0.0

I am working on phonegap (IOS) since 6months, application is ready to go.
but now i want this application to run on visualstudio.

i am useing VS2010 and also installed windows sdk for phone development.i have also install cordova template for windows and its working fine for new development.

but now all i want to use my ready made phonegap application thas was made in xcode for ios in windows.

How can i make it possible ?

**Edits :**
When trying to run my ios application to VS i just replace WWW folder of application in VS and try to run application.it opened emulator well and even called first "Index.html" page but no css/js refrence its getting.even no click events are called. so is there any change in WWW folder structure that i have to perform for windows ? i am new for windows phone.

Comment: So what is a problem to transfer all your html/js/css and images to windows environment? Or I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: @lixas : Thanks for instant reply.i am upgrading my question

Comment: Check slashes, I think in windows \ should be used so separate directories. Also check letter case (uppercase/lowercase). If that does not help- please provide your html code

Comment: @lixas: i think that may be the issue, here is some of error i am getting  **Writing data for /app/www\activityWall.html and length = 47602
Writing data for /app/www\alerts.html and length = 33667**  i tred to replace "\" with "/" but not luckey enough to solve it.i replace it in whole application but still its giving same error. you have any idia where to change path ? ***EDITS:** actually its not error but its output list showing me on output window

Answer (score 1):

1. Buld project; then check all your files exist in CordovaSourceDictionary.xml
2. If not, make sure all your files have a build action Content ([How to set Build Action on a file - Advanced Properties Not Displayed in properties window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498245/how-to-set-build-action-on-a-file-advanced-properties-not-displayed-in-propert))
3. If this didn't help try adding the following lines to your index.html to see if there is any js error (errors will be shown in VS Output Window - Ctrl+Alt+O)

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     window.console = {
>         log: function (str) { window.external.Notify(str); }
>     };
>
>     // output errors to console log
>     window.onerror = function (e) {
>         console.log("window.onerror ::" + JSON.stringify(e));
>     };
>
>     console.log("Installed console !");
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The cordova.js might be different on WP. Try to create a brand new WP project then copy the cordova.js to the www folder and you are good to go.